# How can i extract the meta name:“og:url” content with IMACROS

Tags: firefox, imacros, meta, extract

Im trying to extract the url from  so that it fills up a form with the extracted url but I cant figure out how to extract it. Anyone knows what might work?

Comment: Can you give some sample data and better describe what you are trying to do? Where is your data coming from? Where is this form you are trying to fill?

Comment: Ill try to explain best as i can.
There is this website that has videos embedded, and the only place I can find the url of the video is here - <meta name="og:url" content="URL OF VIDEO">. The only thing i can't do is extract that piece of url.